# POST base64 image using okHTTP, not getting any result

Tags: android, json, okhttp

Edit: Ok, this is my last attempt at this, new code same result. I get a image in the ImageView but no sign of any return-string from the server.

This is what the server expects to get (The image can be url or base64 encoded image):

```
POST /detect HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
app_id: 4985f625
app_key: aa9e5d2ec3b00306b2d9588c3a25d68e
{
    "image":" http://media.kairos.com/kairos-elizabeth.jpg ",
    "selector":"ROLL"
}
```

And this is my code:
MainActivity.java

```
       public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EncodeToBase64 encode = new EncodeToBase64();
    String lastPhotoAsBase64;
    ImageView mImageView;
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/files/Pictures";
    static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;
    String mCurrentPhotoPath;
    String mTestPath = "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.cliff.camera2/files/Pictures/JPEG_20171209_174301_1623885500.jpg";
    String jsonResult;
    TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mImageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Button cameraButton = findViewById(R.id.cameraButton);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);

        cameraButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dispatchTakePictureIntent();


            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            try {
                setPic();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }

    private static int exifToDegrees(int exifOrientation) {
        if (exifOrientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) {
            return 90;
        } else if (exifOrientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180) {
            return 180;
        } else if (exifOrientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) {
            return 270;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public void setPic() throws IOException {
        // Get the dimensions of the View
        int targetW = mImageView.getWidth();
        int targetH = mImageView.getHeight();

        // Get the dimensions of the bitmap
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

        //BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
        int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
        int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

        // Determine how much to scale down the image
        int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW / targetW, photoH / targetH);

        // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
        bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);


        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(mCurrentPhotoPath);
        int rotation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
        int rotationInDegrees = exifToDegrees(rotation);
        //int deg = rotationInDegrees;
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        if (rotation != 0f) {
            matrix.preRotate(rotationInDegrees);
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        }
        lastPhotoAsBase64 = encode.encode(bitmap);
        if(lastPhotoAsBase64 != null) {
            new postData().execute(lastPhotoAsBase64);
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"No base64 data found!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }


    public void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                        "com.example.fileprovider",
                        photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
            }
        }
    }

    public class postData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {
            HttpConnectionActivity hh = new HttpConnectionActivity();
            String temp = hh.HttpConnection(strings[0]);
            textView.setText(temp);
            textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

HttpConnectionActivity.java

```
    public class HttpConnectionActivity  {

    private final static String KAIROS_URL = "https://api.kairos.com/detect";
    private final String KEY = "5232cdde7e35d8de7ac78726060d5a01";
    private final String ID = "9bd755a1";

    String serverResponse;

    public static final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE = MediaType.parse("application/json");
    JSONObject postdata = new JSONObject();



    public String HttpConnection(String image) {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        try {
            postdata.put("image", image);

            RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE, postdata.toString());

            final Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(KAIROS_URL)
                    .post(body)
                    .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .addHeader("app_id", ID)
                    .addHeader("app_key", KEY)
                    .build();

            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            serverResponse = response.body().string();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.getMessage();
        }

        return serverResponse;
    }
}
```

EncodeToBase64.java

```
public class EncodeToBase64 {

    public String encode(Bitmap image) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, baos);
        byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();

        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return encodedImage;
    }
}
```

OnCustomEventListener.java

```
public interface OnCustomEventListener {
    public void onEvent();
}
```

Comment: `public class Json extends AsyncTask...` My god.. Why naming an AsyncTask class Json? Pretty confusing. Unreadable code.

Comment: `Content-Type: application/json`. It looks as if the server want to receive json. What kind of server is it?

Comment: `.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")`. You promise to send json. So far so good.

Comment: `public Json() {
        main = new MainActivity();
    }`. Nonsense. You cannot create activities with new. Remove that code and rethink. What is it that you want? Also do away with getJson() function.

Comment: In the catch block add `return ex.getMessage();`.

Comment: In onPostExecute place a Toast to display String s.

Comment: Ok, tried returning the ex.getMessage() and displaying a Toast in the onPostExecute() but I could not create the Toast in the way I have before (Toast.makeText(this,s,Toast.LENGTHLONG).show().

Is my way of trying this out completly wrong? should I have the asyncTask in the MainActivity and just call the Json class from there ?

Comment: Yes. Live is much easier if the async task is in the activity where you use it. If you make it a public class then you need an interface or callback to bring the result to the calling activity.

Comment: I have made another attempt at the code but am not sure how post it, should I delete everything in the original post and paste all my new code? or what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Depends. But yes you can delete the old code.

Comment: Ok, I updated the post now.

Comment: That is completely different code without an AsyncTask. Moreover you did not tell what works and what not works.

Comment: `"HttpConnection" but I don't know if that name is much better. `. No it is not good. As nobody can see that it is an Activity. Better name it HttpConnectionActivity.

Comment: Ok, so what would a good name for an activity that sends/receives json data? In the bottom of Main Activity is the AsyncTask. Edit: just noticed your answer after posting

Comment: That asynctask does nothing. And you should call it TransferDataTask so every body sees that it is an (async)task.

Comment: You should not have posted the second activity. And you should post the original asynctask. Well a bit modified maybe. Now its a mess.

Comment: Ok so in general terms  what would a god way to connect my classes activities? Should the AsyncTask remain in the activity that sends/receives data?

Comment: Remain? It was outside wasnt it? (As you defined it public). I repeat `Life is much easier if the async task is in the activity where you use it. If you make it a public class then you need an interface or callback to bring the result to the calling activity.`.

Comment: Last try, and if I did know how to code correctly I would, trust me but as I don't this is the best I can come up with right now.

Comment: `} catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.getMessage();
        }`. That should be `} catch (Exception ex) {
            return ex.getMessage();
        }`.

Comment: `textView.setText(temp);
            textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
`. Your app is crashing! Why dont you tell us? You should do this in onPostExecute().